# VS 2010 C# misrecognizes class DataTable

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, datagridview, datatable

I was trying to load a sql query to a DataGridView so I used DataTable to load the SqlDataReader as the dataSource for the data grid view. I have a sample program from my instructor doing the exact same code, but the I get the error only on my project:

```
DataTable table = new DataTable();
table.Load(reader);
DataGridView.DataSource = table;
```

Error at compiler time:

```
Error   1   The event 'System.Windows.Forms.Form.Load' can only appear on the left hand side of += or -=
```

I found this earlier when I was looking at the auto complete, all the method provided by the auto-complete has the type "EventHandler Form".

I double checked I don't have any Form named after "table" (when I move my cursor to 'table' it shows

```
(local variable) DataTable table
```

why is vs saying the [Load method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.load(v=vs.110).aspx) comes from a [Form](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.load(v=vs.110).aspx) ?

ps: I have included/using System.Data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you have a `Form` that's called DataTable. Try specifying `System.Data.DataTable` where you define the variable.

```
System.Data.DataTable table = new System.Data.DataTable();
table.Load(reader);
DataGridView.DataSource = table;
```

And by the way, naming your `DataGridView`, `DataGridView` is extremely dangerous for this exact reason. Please never name custom types after things that are declared in the .NET framework, especially in assemblies you're referencing with yours and *double* especially in assemblies you're `using` in your class. You can even rename it to `DataGridView1` if need be, although something a bit more descriptive would be heavily preferable.

Otherwise, it sounds like you're calling something along the lines of

```
this.Load = Form1_Load;
```

As compared to

```
this.Load += Form1_Load;
```

Comment: Yea, my mistake. I have a form named DataTable... Thank you.